# Calcular el área de un triángulo

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Estoy tratando de calcular el área de un triángolo posicionado en cordenadas cartesianas.

El triángulo se forma de tres puntos:

- a
- b
- c

Cada punto tiene dos cordenadas:

- x
- y

Mi lógica es la siguiente:

1. calcular la distancia entre punto a y punto b y llamarla base
2. calcular un punto exactamente a la mitad de a y b (bisectriz creo se le llama)
3. obtener la distancia entre punto medio de a y b y el punto c y llamarle altura
4. calcular el área con la fórmula base por altura sobre dos

[image: representación gráfica de mi lógica]

La lógica me parece apropiada, pero no estoy pasando las pruebas unitarias del ejercicio.

Este es mi código:

```
function distance(x1,x2,y1,y2){
  return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2) + Math.pow((y2-y1),2));
}

function area(b,h){
  return (b*h)/2;
}

function midlePoint(x1,x2,y1,y2){
  return new Point((x1+x2)/2,(y1+y2)/2);
}

function triangleArea(triangle){
  var {a,b,c} = triangle;
  var {x:x1,y:y1} = a;
  var {x:x2,y:y2} = b;
  var base = distance(x1,x2,y1,y2);
  console.log(base);
  var {x:midlex,y:midley} = midlePoint(x1,x2,y1,y2);
  var {x:x3,y:y3} = c;
  var height = distance( midlex,x3,midley,y3);
  console.log(height);
  return area(base,height);
}
```

Estas son las pruebas unitarias:

```
Test.assertEquals(+triangleArea(new Triangle(new Point(10, 10), new Point(40, 10), new Point(10, 50))).toFixed(6), 600)
Test.assertEquals(+triangleArea(new Triangle(new Point(15, -10), new Point(40, 20), new Point(20, 50))).toFixed(6), 675)
```

¿Cuál será el problema?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tu problema está en que asumes erróneamente que la altura de tu triángulo pasa por el punto medio de lo que estableces como la base. Tu lógica se cumple sólo para triángulos isósceles y cuando escoges adecuadamente la base.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Para calcular el área de cualquier triángulo, dados sus vértices, debes usar un algoritmo diferente al que tratas de implementar.

La fórmula viene dada por:

```
Área = (1/2)*(|nAB·AC|)
```

Donde `|nAB·AC|` es el valor absoluto del producto punto o producto escalar de los vectores `nAB` y `AC`. Siendo `nAB` el vector normal (perpendicular) a `AB`

Paso 1.
Calculas el vector `AB: (Xb - Xa, Yb - Ya) = (Xab,Yab)`

Paso 2.
Calculas el vector normal a AB (es la dirección del vector perpendicular a AB)
`nAB: (Xn, Yn) = (Yab, -Xab)`

Paso 3.
Calculas el vector `AC: (Xc - Xa, Yc - Ya) = (Xac,Yac)`

Paso 4.
Calculas el producto punto (producto escalar) de los vectores nAB y AC: (Xn * Xac) +  (Yn * Yac)

Paso 5.
Calculas el Área del triángulo aplicando la fórmula: A = (1/2)(|productoEscalar|)

**RESULTADO**

¿Cómo puede quedar tu función? Bueno, eso ya lo decides tu, yo sólo te doy un ejemplo:

```js
var a = {x: 2, y: 0}
var b = {x: 3, y: 4}
var c = {x: -2, y: 5}

function vectorDireccion(v,w) {
  return {x: w.x-v.x, y: w.y - v.y}
}

function productoEscalar(v,w) {
  return (v.x * w.x) + (v.y * w.y);
}

function vectorNormal(v) {
  return {x: v.y, y: -v.x}
}

function moduloEscalar(escalar) {
  return escalar < 0 ? (-1 * escalar) : escalar;
}

function calcAreaTriangVertices(a, b, c) {
  var vecAB = vectorDireccion(a, b);
  var vecNAB = vectorNormal(vecAB);
  var vecAC = vectorDireccion(a, c);
  var pEscalar = productoEscalar(vecNAB, vecAC);
  return ((1/2) * moduloEscalar(pEscalar));
}

var area = calcAreaTriangVertices(a, b, c);

console.log(area);
```

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.

Saludos

Referencias:

[Triángulo Isósceles - Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tri%C3%A1ngulo_is%C3%B3sceles)

[Producto Escalar - Wikipedia](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producto_escalar)

Comment: Tu algoritmo funciona, aunque no entiendo completamente el por qué hacerlo así. Saludos.

Comment: @RuslanLópez. Existen algúnos métodos distintos para lograr el objetivo. Si deseas una explicación más amplia, con gusto te la doy. Mi algoritmo se basa en cálculos geométricos aplicables al problema de hallar el área de cualquier triángulo si se conocen sus vértices. Tu algoritmo, aunque también se basa en cálculos geométricos, no es aplicable a todos los triángulos, sólo funciona con triángulos isósceles y si escoges la arista que tiene tamaño diferente como base. La altura de todo triángulo isósceles bisecta a la base en el punto medio. Eso sólo ocurre en triángulos isósceles.

Comment: Sí, sería bueno conocer una explicación mas teórica ya que hay otras soluciones aparentemente más simples como ` Math.abs((b.x - a.x) * (c.y - a.y) - (c.x - a.x) * (b.y - a.y))/2`

Comment: Si te fijas bien, la fórmula que acabas de postear, hace exactamente lo que hace mi algoritmo en una sola línea. Realmente es más simple por el hecho de estar en una sola línea. Pero explicarla es otro asunto. Por eso la separé en partes, para que se entendiera el procedimiento. Mi respuesta no sería bien recibida si solo copio y pego una fórmula sin más explicaciones. Si quieres una explicación más teórica podemos hablar en privado y aclaro tus dudas. Gracias

Comment: Basta con algunos links a los conceptos. Gracias.